# Convert HTML to Plain Text using c++

Tags: c++, html, text

I am doing mail parsing application which required to convert the HTML file to Plain Text. 
regarding this i have found some scripts which does conversion. 
I want to do same thing in C++.

So please suggest me any Cross platform and open source C++ libraries for converting HTML to Plain Text.

Thanks in advance 
Regards
Subbi

Comment: What do you mean with "convert"? Html IS plain text! Do you want to strip the html tags?

Comment: yes .I want to strip the HTML tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using regular expression extracting html tags and save result as file text. But it not simple. Use this help class [DEELX - Regular Expression Engine](http://www.regexlab.com/deelx/).

Comment: Thank your for the link to DEELX. I dont always like having to deal with including boost.

Answer (score 3):

After trying out a few options, I think the easier way to do it with large scale is to use elinks.

in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install elinks
elinks -dump a.html > a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [html2text](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/). It's a command tool and not a pure lib, but contains code which strips and converts html. So you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As 'obvious' as it may sound you can just keep all the text between `>` & `<`

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted my question. my desire is to convert  HTML to Text.

Comment: @subbi : the HTML tags are enclosed between < & > so stripping them will give you the text: everything between > & <. Of course I'm oversimplifying it, you'll need to take care of a few special tags (i.e. <script>) and special constructs like &<...>; (i.e. &nbsp;, &lt;)

Answer (score 1):

I post the c++ version for Windows [which originally came from @Ben Anderson's C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407272/1613961).
Note, the code isn't quite robust yet. Also all the leading and ending newlines would be trimmed.

```
// The trimming method comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1798170/1613961
wstring trim(const std::wstring& str, std::wstring& newline = L"\r\n")
{
    const auto strBegin = str.find_first_not_of(newline);
    if (strBegin == std::string::npos)
        return L""; // no content

    const auto strEnd = str.find_last_not_of(newline);
    const auto strRange = strEnd - strBegin + 1;

    return str.substr(strBegin, strRange);
}

wstring HtmlToText(wstring htmlTxt) {

    std::wregex stripFormatting(L"<[^>]*(>|$)"); //match any character between '<' and '>', even when end tag is missing

    wstring s1 = std::regex_replace(htmlTxt, stripFormatting, L"");
    wstring s2 = trim(s1);
    wstring s3 = std::regex_replace(s2, std::wregex(L"\\&nbsp;"), L" ");
    return s3;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but it should also include html entities conversion (you know, stuff like `&lt;`)