# C# Clean Rss Description

Tags: c#, html, rss, plaintext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert Html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286813/how-do-you-convert-html-to-plain-text)

I want to show some Rss feeds in my application. But I do not want to show whole description.
I just want to show first couple of sentence of rss description.

Since lots of Rss feeds are coming as html, I want to convert to plain text and get sub string out of it.

Is there any way to html -> plain text in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see filbys answer on [How do you convert Html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286813/how-do-you-convert-html-to-plain-text/286825#286825) for how to do this. You should also see Judah Himango's answer on the same question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286813/how-do-you-convert-html-to-plain-text/1121515#1121515). He basically says that you should use the [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which will do it for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Appreciated.