# How to remove line blank with regex html to plain text?

Tags: c#, regex, nopcommerce

I using regex to convert html to plain text.

Can you help me to remove line blank with regex

My html:

```
<div class="short-description">
<div class="short-description">
<div class="short-description">
<div class="short-description">
<div class="short-description">
<div class="short-description">
<div class="short-description">
<div class="short-description">
<div class="short-description">
<ul style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana; color: #000000; font-size: 13px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 1; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: #ffffff;">
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">Processor: Intel® Xeon® E5-2403 1.80GHz, 10M Cache, 6.4GT/s QPI, No Turbo, 4C, 80W, Max Mem 1066MHz</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">Memory:&nbsp; 8GB (4x2GB) 1333MHz, Single Ranked LV RDIMMs up to 16GB</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">Hard Drive: 1TB 7.2K RPM NL SAS 3.5-inch Hot Plug</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">Storage Controller: H310 raid controller Support RAID 0, 1, 5, 10</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">File Access Protocols: CIFS, NFS, FTP, SMB3.0, SMB Direct (RDMA)</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">Internal Drive Support: 4 x 3.5" hot-plug drive bays</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">Power: 1 x 550W Power Supply (redundant)</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">OS: Window Storage 2008 Workgroup R2 Edition</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">Form Factor 1U rack mount system</li>
<li style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: Tahoma, Verdana !important;">Warranty: 3 Year ProSupport and NBD On-site Service</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
                            </div>
```

And my regex:

```
Regex.Replace(Model.MetaDescription, @"<(.|\n)*?>","")
```

This result (image):
[Result regex.replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIBoS.png%5C)

How like in bellow image
[Result regex.replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD41f.png)

Comment: What do you mean by *line blank*? Do you mean linebreaks?

Comment: Yes, i want remove line break that empty content

Comment: This is code in live: http://regexr.com/3cmmi

Comment: Don't use RegEx with HTML. RegEx is for regular languages and HTML isn't one. You should use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As it has mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1121515/2263683), you can use the free and open source [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Check the [sample](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/62772#52179)

> a method that converts from HTML to plain text.
>
> ```
> var plainText = ConvertToPlainText(string html);
> ```
>
> Feed it an HTML string like
>
> > <b>hello world!</b><br
> >     /><i>it is me!
> >     !</i>
>
> And you'll get a plain text result like:
>
> ```
> hello world!
> it is me!
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to remove anything between angle brackets `<>` and also remove newlines, then try this regex

```
@"<[^>]*>|\n"
```

However, as Alex Jolig suggests, use HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: @"<.*>|\n" also remove text,

Comment: In result these line blank in top and bottom, I want remove it, and retain text.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RegEx with HTML. RegEx is for regular languages and HTML isn't one. You should use HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML.

It becomes very easy:

```
var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

string[] lines =
    document
        .DocumentNode
        .Descendants("li")
        .Select(x => System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(x.InnerText))
        .ToArray();

string text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

With that I get:

```
Processor: Intel® Xeon® E5-2403 1.80GHz, 10M Cache, 6.4GT/s QPI, No Turbo, 4C, 80W, Max Mem 1066MHz
Memory:  8GB (4x2GB) 1333MHz, Single Ranked LV RDIMMs up to 16GB
Hard Drive: 1TB 7.2K RPM NL SAS 3.5-inch Hot Plug
Storage Controller: H310 raid controller Support RAID 0, 1, 5, 10
File Access Protocols: CIFS, NFS, FTP, SMB3.0, SMB Direct (RDMA)
Internal Drive Support: 4 x 3.5" hot-plug drive bays
Power: 1 x 550W Power Supply (redundant)
OS: Window Storage 2008 Workgroup R2 Edition
Form Factor 1U rack mount system
Warranty: 3 Year ProSupport and NBD On-site Service
```