# convert html to plain text using c#

Tags: c#, html, .net

i use this method to convert html to plaint text but it have some bugs in this html tags  <H1,2,3,..>

Method :

```
public string HtmlToPlainText(string htmlText)
    {
        //const string tagWhiteSpace = @"(>|$)(\W|\n|\r)+<";//matches one or more (white space or line breaks) between '>' and '<'
        const string stripFormatting = @"<[^>]*(>|$)";//match any character between '<' and '>', even when end tag is missing
        const string lineBreak = @"<(br|BR)\s{0,1}\/{0,1}>";//matches: <br>,<br/>,<br />,<BR>,<BR/>,<BR />
        var lineBreakRegex = new Regex(lineBreak, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var stripFormattingRegex = new Regex(stripFormatting, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        //var tagWhiteSpaceRegex = new Regex(tagWhiteSpace, RegexOptions.Multiline);

        var text = htmlText;
        //Decode html specific characters
        text = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text);
        //Remove tag whitespace / line breaks
        //text = tagWhiteSpaceRegex.Replace(text, "><");
        //Replace < br /> with line breaks
        text = lineBreakRegex.Replace(text, Environment.NewLine);
        //Strip formatting
        text = stripFormattingRegex.Replace(text, string.Empty);
        return text;
    }
```

> **this is my html text** :
>
> ```
> <h3> This is a simple title </h3>
> </br>
> <p>Lorem ipsum <b> dolor sit </b> amet consectetur, <i>adipisicing elit.</i> </p>
> ```
>
> **This is my result** :
>
> This is a simple title   Lorem ipsum dolor sit  amet consectetur,
> adipisicing elit.
>
> **The result should be** :
>
> This is a simple title
>
> Lorem ipsum  dolor sit  amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.

I think the error is from Strip formatting. How can i solve it?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to extract data from html.

Comment: Did you mean `<br />` instead of `</br>`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Why did you disclose that your question come a solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407272/1248177)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert Html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286813/how-do-you-convert-html-to-plain-text)

Comment: Please explain (with examples, test-cases, etc.) how your are not a duplicate of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407272/1248177).

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML is not an easy task (even for a subset of HTML). If regex feels like a good solution for this task it is actually not that great. To parse HTML, you should use ... an HTML parser. In C#, `AngleSharp` and the `HTMLAgilityPack` are the most common solution. Here is an example with AngleSharp:

```
using System;
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Html.Parser;

class MyClass {
    static void Main() {
        //Use the default configuration for AngleSharp
        var config = Configuration.Default;

        //Create a new context for evaluating webpages with the given config
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);

        //Source to be parsed
        var source = @"<h3> This is a simple title </h3>
</br>
<p>Lorem ipsum <b> dolor sit </b> amet consectetur, <i>adipisicing elit.</i> </p>
";

        //Create a parser to specify the document to load (here from our fixed string)
        var parser = context.GetService<IHtmlParser>();
        var document = parser.ParseDocument(source);

        //Do something with document like the following
        Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentElement.TextContent);
    }
}
```

[Try it Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6HrJy0)