# How to limit text characters in column while still allowing unlimited HTML styles?

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, limit

If I have a column for notes/comments in a table, what is an appropriate way / is there a way to store a limited number of characters (say 600) while still allowing for unlimited HTML style markup?

The only way I could think of is to enforce the limit at the backend but I'm concerned it might not be enough.

Comment: use TEXT as column type and so the size doewsn't matter as long you don't exceed 2 TB

Comment: @nbk Sure I thought of that but now I have no control over the limit of the note/comment itself. My question was whether there's a way to enforce the limit in the database.

Comment: before you store the text check the number of character, without mark up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you convert Html to plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286813/how-do-you-convert-html-to-plain-text)

Comment: `text` @nbk? Why recommend a data type that has been deprecated for 18 years?

Comment: Just use NVARCHAR(MAX), and do whatever validation you need (if needed at all) on the frontend side of things. @ThomA, maybe it's getting a comeback

Comment: First, **do not use `TEXT`**. Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Enforcing plain text length would best be done on the application side  due to the very limited string processing capabilities in SQL Server. You can use `HtmlUtilities.ConvertToPlainText()` function as described in the above linked question, If you insist, you could add a column constraint that calls a user-defined function that implements the check and returns a bit result. That function would then need to parse and remove all of the HTML tags and check the length.

Comment: Like ANSI-89 joins in Oracle, @siggemannen ? I *hope* not.

Comment: A curious requirement... why limit it?

Comment: @DaleK Because that's the requirement and I'm only managing the database in this project. So, I have no control over the development of the API and I want to make sure everything is in order even if the API doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HTML is really (X)HTML, it is possible to use SQL Server XML data type and built-in XQuery language capabilities.

XQuery allows to retrieve textual data only excluding HTML tags.

Even embedded CSS `<style>...</style>` could be easily taken out of the equation.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, notes XML);
INSERT @tbl (notes) VALUES
(N'<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        table  {border-collapse: collapse; } 
        th  {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;} 
        th, td  { text-align: center; padding: 8px;} 
        tr.yellow td  {background-color: yellow;} 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>State</th>
          <th>City</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr align="center" valign="center" class="yellow">
          <td>1</td>
          <td>FL</td>
          <td>Miami</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center" valign="center">
          <td>2</td>
          <td>FL</td>
          <td>Orlando</td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center" valign="center">
          <td>3</td>
          <td>TX</td>
          <td>Dallas</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , textOnly, LEN(textOnly) AS LenTextOnly
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT notes.query('
    for $x in /html//*[local-name()!="style"]/text()
    return $x
    ').value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) AS t1(textOnly);
```

**Output**

| ID | textOnly | LenTextOnly |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | No.StateCity1FLMiami2FLOrlando3TXDallas | 39 |

Comment: This is nice but a single <br> would mess it up :/

Comment: I pointed out about XHTML, so `<br>` would become `</br>`. Overall, the application layer can enforce that it is XHTML.

Comment: I didn't know about XQuery before, do you know where can I find other built-in features like that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16